# hql query bringing in too much data

Tags: nhibernate, hql

I would like the query below to return an Employee object that has Allocations which fall within the requested range of dates.

The query returns all Allocations though. It is also doing three queries to the database, which I am not sure I understand (the third one might be because I have a batch size of 100 on Activity Subjects).

How can I change this query to efficiently return only allocations for the period requested?

Cheers,
Berryl

DATABASE SQLS:

```
NHibernate: select resource0_.ResourceId as ResourceId0_, resource0_.BusinessId as BusinessId0_, resource0_.ResourceName as Resource4_0_, resource0_.OwnerName as OwnerName0_, resource0_.EmployeeNumber as Employee6_0_, resource0_.FirstName as FirstName0_, resource0_.LastName as LastName0_, resource0_.DepartmentId as Departme9_0_, resource0_.ResourceType as Resource2_0_ from Resources resource0_ 
inner join Allocations allocation1_ on resource0_.ResourceId=allocation1_.ResourceId 
where resource0_.BusinessId=@p0 
and (allocation1_.StartTime between @p1 and @p2);@p0 = '000001' [Type: String (0)], @p1 = 12/27/2010 12:00:00 AM [Type: DateTime (0)], @p2 = 1/2/2011 11:59:59 PM [Type: DateTime (0)]

NHibernate: SELECT allocation0_.ResourceId as ResourceId1_, allocation0_.AllocationId as Allocati1_1_, allocation0_.AllocationId as Allocati1_2_0_, allocation0_.ActivitySubjectId as Activity2_2_0_, allocation0_.ResourceId as ResourceId2_0_, allocation0_.StartTime as StartTime2_0_, allocation0_.EndTime as EndTime2_0_, allocation0_.PostingTime as PostingT6_2_0_ 
FROM Allocations allocation0_ WHERE allocation0_.ResourceId=@p0;@p0 = 98304 [Type: Int32 (0)]

NHibernate: SELECT activitysu0_.ActivitySubjectId as Activity1_3_0_, activitysu0_.BusinessId as BusinessId3_0_, activitysu0_.Description as Descript4_3_0_, activitysu0_.ActivitySubjectType as Activity2_3_0_ 
FROM ActivitySubjects activitysu0_ WHERE activitysu0_.ActivitySubjectId in (@p0, @p1, @p2, @p3);@p0 = 32784 [Type: Int32 (0)], @p1 = 32854 [Type: Int32 (0)], @p2 = 32860 [Type: Int32 (0)], @p3 = 32861 [Type: Int32 (0)]
```

HQL QUERY

```
    public Resource GetResourceForDateRange<T>(string businessId, DateRange period) where T : Resource
    {
        Check.RequireStringValue(businessId, "businessId");
        Check.RequireNotNull(period);

        const string hql =
            @"
                                select r 
                                from Resource r 
                                inner join r.Allocations as a
                                where r.BusinessId = :businessId 
                                and a.TimeRange.StartTime between :periodStart and :periodEnd";

        return _session.CreateQuery(hql)
            .SetString("businessId", businessId)
            .SetDateTime("periodStart", period.Start)
            .SetDateTime("periodEnd", period.End)
            .UniqueResult<Resource>();

    }
```

MAPPING

```
<id name="Id" type="System.Int32" unsaved-value="0">
  <column name="ResourceId" />
  <generator class="hilo" />
</id>

<discriminator column="ResourceType" type="System.String" />

<property name="BusinessId" length="50" not-null="true" unique="true" unique-key="DomainSignature" index="ResourceDomainSignature" />
<property name="ResourceName" length="75" not-null="true" />
<property name="OwnerName" length="75" not-null="true" />

<set access="field.camelcase-underscore" cascade="all-delete-orphan" inverse="true" name="Allocations">
  <key foreign-key="Allocations_Resource_FK">
    <column name="ResourceId" />
  </key>
  <one-to-many class="Allocations.Allocation" />
</set>

<subclass name="Resources.HumanResources.Employee" discriminator-value="EMPLOYEE">
    ...
</subclass>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason it's doing 3 queries is likely due to lazy loading being off. So it's loading all objects associated with the entity Resource. This is why it's getting all Allocations.

Try doing a fetch join

```
from Resource r 
left join fetch r.Allocations as a
where r.BusinessId = :businessId 
and a.TimeRange.StartTime between :periodStart and :periodEnd
```

Comment: lazy loading for the class is not off, but the fetch got it back to one query along with the expected results. thanks!